# Best way to raise validation error before save at model level in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a background job wherein I am creating `MyModel` using `get_or_create` method from a data in dictionary.
I have a condition to check and if not satisfied just log the error.

Basically I am looping through a list of dict of data and calling the `get_or_create`.

If it is at the `form` level, then I am using `clean` method but since this is being done in the backend what would be the best way to validate before save and log if validation fails?

I would like to know how to validate on both - `before` `create` or `update`.

Should I use `pre_save` signal or just `clean_field_name` or `clean` method?

Answer (score 0):

Django `get_or_create` method use `save` method to create the model. so clean methods will not call here. your best chance is to override `.save()` of your model and raise your validation:

```
 def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not some_condition:
        raise ValidationError
    else:
        super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```